# Filter on json-object properties in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, object

I have a table called groups where I have a field "group_users".

In every group the group_users is stored as json like this:

```
{
  "user1": {
     "name":"...",
     "notifications": true,
  }
  "user2": {
     ...
  }
}
```

How do I fetch every group that a certain user is apart of?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This would be so much easier with a properly normalized data model.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: While you can use json in PostgreSQL does not mean you ***have*** to.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ok thanks for you comment, will look into that. I am using version 13

Answer (score 0):

With Postgres 13, you can use a JSON path expression:

```
select *
from groups
where group_users @@ 'strict $.**.name == "Someuser"'
```

This assumes that `group_users` is a `jsonb` column which it should be. If it's not you need to cast it `group_users::jsonb`